# taking the html title to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, var

How do I get the variable in the titleText "Some Name" from the JS file to populate or take the title from the hyperlink "sometitle" in the HTML code?

**JS**

```
var randomtext={ titleText:"Some Name",}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="css" title="sometitle" href="#">Your HTML Here</a>
```

I would like the  JS to then change to:

**JS**

```
var randomtext={ titleText:"sometitle",}
```

Titletext name coming from the title in the anchor of the hyperlink

I tried the following and it didn't work

**JS**

```
    var randomtext={ 
titleText:document.getElementsByClassName('css')[0]; randomtext.titleText = anchor.getAttribute('title');,
title2: "name1",
title3: "name3",
title4: "name4",

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to identify the `<a>` element somehow. The easiest way would be to give it an ID.

Then, using `document.getElementById`, you can access the hyperlink inside your script. Once that's done, you can access its title with `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

**HTML**

```
<a id="myLink" class="css" title="sometitle" href="#">Your HTML Here</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var link = document.getElementById("myLink");

// Take the title from the link
var randomText = { titleText: link.getAttribute("title") };

// Change the link's title
link.setAttribute("title", randomText.titleText);
```

*I hope this is what you asked for, because, if I'm honest, I'm not really sure what you wanted to say.*

Comment: @DavidSmith It does. Look at this example I made: http://jsbin.com/akEHELI/1 | It outputs the links title.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you want to get the "title" attribute on the anchor, and use it to set the value of the `titleText` property on your `randomtext` object:

**JS**

```
var randomtext={ titleText:"Some Name"}
// a more specific class name or id would be better suited here
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('css')[0];  
randomtext.titleText = anchor.getAttribute('title');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSaqh/)

**Update**

I'm not sure why you want to include all the of the logic in your object definition, but your current javascript is invalid. If you absolutely *must* assign a value to the titleText property when you create your randomText object, the following should work:

```
   var randomtext={ 
     // this immediately invokes a function 
     // which looks for the first anchor
     // and returns it's title attribute
     // that attribute is then assigned to the titleText property
     // on the object.
     titleText:(function () {
         var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('css')[0];     
         return anchor.getAttribute('title');
     })(),
    title2: "name1",
    title3: "name3",
    title4: "name4",
}
```

Comment: You are correct, I would like to take the title from the anchor and use it to set the value of the property in the JS script. I tried both codes and neither of them worked.

Comment: The JS code you wrote is invalid. You can either rewrite your code as I have written it in my answer, or wrap it in a [iife](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and return a value that you want assigned to the titleText property. Also, your JS needs to be a. included after the DOM has loaded or b. use a "ready" function to wait until the DOM has loaded.

Comment: I have no option of rewriting it as it a pretty large code. I was hoping I could insert something after the titletext: that would do it. by adding the following line gets the page title that works. (titleText: document.title,) but I need it to get the anchor title not the page title. You might need to explain the last part I don't understand it

Comment: @DavidSmith Sorry if I was unclear. The javascript code that you tried (listed in your edited question) is invalid. You cannot have multiple javascript statements in a property assignment. I've updated my post with a corrected version of your code.